# SwiftUI app work in preview but not in simulator

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm making an app for a school project where I try to calculate the weight of a person on different planets. The  ContentView file works fine in the preview, but only shows NavigationBar.title in the simulator / iPhone. Here is the code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    var planets: [Planet] = []
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            List(planets) { planet in
                PlanetCell(planet: planet)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Sun"))

        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(planets: testData)
    }
}
#endif

struct PlanetCell : View {
    let planet : Planet
    var body: some View {
        return NavigationLink(destination: PlanetDetail(planet: planet)){
            Text(planet.name)
        }
    }
}
```

edit- swift file called Planet

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
struct Planet : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var g : Float
    var imageName : String { return name }
}

#if DEBUG
let testData = [

    Planet(name: "Mercury", g: 3.724),
    Planet(name: "Venus", g: 8.918),
    Planet(name: "Earth", g: 9.8),
    Planet(name: "Mars", g: 3.724),
    Planet(name: "Jupiter", g: 22.932),
    Planet(name: "Saturn", g: 9.114),
    Planet(name: "Uranus", g: 9.016),
    Planet(name: "Neptune", g: 10.976)

]

#endif
```

Comment: do you see an empty SwiftUI list (Table View)? or no table view at all? can you post a simulator screen shot?

Comment: @F.Jihad https://imgur.com/gallery/7MV1EsB

Comment: As I expected, your code is okay and showing UI but your Data array is empty that is why it doesn't populate any data. You have 0 planet in your planets array

Comment: I made a struct called Planet, which has data(which is displayed in the preview). Could you show how i can fix that?

Comment: your sample data is wrapped inside the `#if DEBUG` closure, so it will work only in preview

Answer (score 3):

Actually your code is fine and does what it suppose to do, your `testData` is available on debug mode only (Preview). That is why you don't see it in real device or simulator, in order to see an actual data you need to fill your data array `planets` in your `ContentView` file so it should have some planets in it just like your `testData`. You should modify your `ContentView` as follow:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    var planets: [Planet] = [

        Planet(name: "Mercury", g: 3.724),
        Planet(name: "Venus", g: 8.918),
        Planet(name: "Earth", g: 9.8),
        Planet(name: "Mars", g: 3.724),
        Planet(name: "Jupiter", g: 22.932),
        Planet(name: "Saturn", g: 9.114),
        Planet(name: "Uranus", g: 9.016),
        Planet(name: "Neptune", g: 10.976)

    ]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            List(planets) { planet in
                PlanetCell(planet: planet)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Sun"))

        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(planets: testData)
    }
}
#endif

struct PlanetCell : View {
    let planet : Planet
    var body: some View {
        return NavigationLink(destination: PlanetDetail(planet: planet)){
            Text(planet.name)
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend you see how you can use `ObservableObject` and `State` to bind the UI with your Model changes, you can checkout this tutorial: [SwiftUI by Example](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui)

Comment: Years later... Super helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In ContentView change

```
var planets: [Planet] = []
```

to

```
var planets: [Planet] = testData
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you pass a non-empty list (`planets`) to your `ContentView` when your initialize it?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean `ContentView(planets: testData)`, if yes, then I have in the code above. If no, could you show how to do it as I'm fairly new to iOS programming.

Comment: The code inside `ContentView_Previews` is used for the Xcode Preview. This is why your Xcode Preview works. However, for the Simulator (or Device) this code is not used. Could you show us where you use your `ContentView` object? In the `SceneDelegate` maybe?

Comment: Wait, I didn't know we had to use `ContentView` object. I learnt swiftUI from a couple of tutorials and they all work without having to write code in `SceneDelegate`. I made a file where the data to display when a cell is clicked on. Sorry if this question is stupid- how do i make a `ContentView` object.

Comment: I encourage you to follow Apple tutorials on the matter. See [Building Lists and Navigation](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation), it should fit your needs.